# the _id column of MMS-SMS database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am accessing Android MMS-SMS database:

```
Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
String[] projection = {"_id"};
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

//Is the id the same as the id in corresponding SMS or MMS table?
long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
```

My question is simple, is the "_id" column holds the same id value of corresponding table (for SMS `"content://sms"`; for MMS `"content://mms"`) ? If it is not, how can I get the id of the message in SMS or MMS table from the `cursor` I got?

What I want to do is I want to use this id to query the corresponding SMS or MMS table.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want fetch mms-sms by "_id" column from "content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true"
try

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/"+id), new String[] {"_id","body","date","type","error_code","ct_t","_data","m_type"}, null, null, null);
```

"id" is value "_id" column.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are doing that in wrong way. You should add your wanted values about sms to the `projection` like that;

```
String[] projection = {"Conversations._ID"};
```

then you can take sms id with that:

```
long id = cursor.getLong(0);
```

If you want to take another information from Sms, add your keys to `projection` like:

```
String[] projection = {"Conversations._ID", "Conversations.ADDRESS", "Conversations.BODY"};
```

then;

```
long id = cursor.getLong(0);
String address = cursor.getString(1); // tel number
String body = cursor.getString(2); // content of message
```

**Edit:** You should also check your uri and try that:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Conversations.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
```

Good luck.

Comment: What about MMS id? use Mms._ID as projection ?

Comment: Yes in this way i can take sms, mms and calls. Same approximation.

Comment: Do you know how do I know is the current row an SMS or MMS ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me, I got `no such column: Mms._ID` , are you using the same uri as I am using? I mean `Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");`

Comment: I thought you are only taking your sms box or mms box. But i see you want Conversations.

Comment: Thank you, but are you sure about your code? Again, I got  `no such column: Conversations._ID`, are you using the same uri as I am using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72351/discussion-between-batuhan-coskun-and-leem-fin).